# Noise on monitor (multiple white horizontal lines)

Tags: display, hardware-failure, noise

Any help with the below issue is much appreciated! It's seen on a monitor which had worked perfectly for years, after shipping to another person (no visible external damage) within 2 days of use.

Multiple short horizontal white lines ('noise') are visible on the monitor which keep on changing places and kind of having a shimmering effect, as can be seen in the video.

https://youtu.be/e2QVyuH7FWM

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use words to describe your issue fully, so it's searchable & useful to future seekers. Posting a link to a video makes this question only even vaguely useful so long as the video is there.

Comment: No guarantee it is a monitor  issue.

Comment: Post updated with more details to ease future searches

Answer (score 0):

Is it the multiple short white horizontal lines which are the problem? That's noise, which can be introduced by the cable or video card. Swap out the video cable, and move the monitor so the cable follows a different path from PC to monitor.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem, white line segments seen on the display. Did not have this issue ever on my personal PC, even when used non stop for 6+ hours. Cable changed but same issue persists, will change the PC as well and report back, thank you!